# Python Package installed with pip could not be found (Windows)

Tags: installation, package, python-sphinx

I have been given two large undocumented C++ and Python projects and I want to understand their structures. For this I would like to create class diagrams with the Python package Sphinx. I opened the command line on Windows 10, installed Python 3.9.6 from the Windows Store and then I typed

```
pip install sphinx
```

to install Sphinx globally. When I rerun the command, it tells me that Sphinx is already installed. When I run

```
sphinx-quickstart
```

an error is displayed telling me I mistyped the command or that it could not be found. I think Windows does not know the path to Sphinx and I do not know how to fix the problem. I sticked to the [official installation guide](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html#install-pypi).

Comment: Have you tried typing `sphinx-build --version` after installation just as per the installation guide?

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/installation.html#using-virtual-environments says "When installing Sphinx using pip, it is highly recommended to use virtual environments, which isolate the installed packages from the system packages, thus removing the need to use administrator privileges." Your question indicates you have not done that.